# Браузер уменьшает толщину border?

Tags: html, border

Здравствуйте!
У меня такая проблема: браузер Chrome отображает ширину border у html элементов не такую, как задана в стилях, а уменьшенную в 0.8 раз. Моё разрешение экрана на ноутбуке 1920 x 1080. (Windows 10). Но браузер Chrome (и не только он) масштабирует так, что моя ширина становится = 1536 пикселей. То есть тоже уменьшает в 0.8 раз. Но в IE11 и Edge бордер отображается как надо. Хотелось бы понять, как сделать одинаковое поведение во всех браузерах? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Не-не-не, тут нужен код, чтобы все вместе могли протестить и сказать, что проблема в тебе, а не в браузерах (наверняка так и есть). Так что давай код.

Comment: Точно, забыл прикрепить скрин. В общем захожу на htmlbook (http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-style), открываю Development Tools и вижу то самое изменение размеров. Скрин: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5vKLuqulVTSYUFjc2JkRFNPTTg

Comment: Можно вот тут - http://jsfiddle.net/uzQJE/14/ наглядно проверить в разных браузерах. А если жать Ctrl+ и Ctrl- (изменяя масштаб) и перегружать страницу, становится совсем загадочно :)

Comment: Вот тут в Windows https://monosnap.com/file/HoeilrQdFmhM6K56VIq1TlXdlN9Ax0 у вас что?

Comment: Да, у меня выставлено точно также.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот баг Chrome, который встречается в самых разных версиях браузера. Отчего он возникает - точного мнения пока нет, скорее всего из-за особенностей субпиксельного рендеринга Webkit. Аналогичный баг имеется в Firefox, насчет Safari ничего не могу сказать (у меня Safari на Мас работал корректно).

Проблема имеет [статус "Открыто" в баг-трекере](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696215&q=border-width&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Ниже примеры, где можно наглядно проверить ширину `border` в разных браузерах.
http://jsfiddle.net/uzQJE/14/ и http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqFgi (код идентичен). При этом в одном примере браузер может работать корректно, а в другом - нет.

`Ctrl+` и `Ctrl-`  (изменение масштаба просмотра) дают неожиданные результаты.

Chrome для PC имеет баг, на Chrome для Mac OS результаты Chrome были корректны.

Что делать с этим - неизвестно. Судя по тому, что обсуждать эту проблему начали как минимум [пять лет назад](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863430/strange-border-width-behavior-in-chrome-floating-point-border-width)  - вряд ли стоит ожидать ее быстрого решения :) 
На самом деле ее видели "почти все" - просто она обычно незаметна невооруженным глазом.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Теперь все ясно.